# iOS How To Convert NSDictionary To URL QueryString In Simplest Way

Tags: ios

How can I convert `NSDictionary` To `URL` `QueryString` in iOs ?

for example :

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"a":@1, @"b":@2}
NSString queryString = convert(params); // a=1&b=2
```

Comment: There isn't a simple way.